# Show that $Ax=0, Bx=0$ share the same solution space iff there is some invertible $P$ s.t. $B=PA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is said in the title, suppose $A,B\in M_{m\times n}(K)$, where $K$ is some infinite number field.

If we regard $A,B$ as linear maps from $K^n$ to $K^m$, then they share the same solution space $\Leftrightarrow$ $Ker A=Ker B$. And since kernels are orthogonally complementary to row spaces, it is equivalent to  $R(A)=R(B)$ where $R$ denotes the row space of a matrix. Therefore the row vector groups  of $A,B$ are equivalent, which means every row  of $A$ can be expressed as a linear combination of those of $B$, and vice versa. But since $A,B$ may not have full row rank, I'm having trouble showing such a invertible $P$ exists.

I believe I'm on the right track but may miss something. Can you help me? Best regards!

EDIT: Thanks go to @DavidP who provided a very good argument using RREF, which is by far slicker than any other approach I could imagine. But I am still looking for a way to complete my proof, which I think is going to be an ok one.

So the real question is, if two row vector groups
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1\\ \vdots\\ \alpha_m\end{bmatrix},\quad B=\begin{bmatrix} \beta_1\\ \vdots\\ \beta_m\end{bmatrix}$$
are equivalent, is it true that there exists some invertible $P\in M_m(K)$ such that
$$B=PA$$?

Comment: The matrix $P$ is a product of elementary matrices. This fact can easily be proven from the uniqueness of the row-reduced echelon form of a matrix. Same homogeneous solution space, same RREF. There exist $E_1,...,E_r$ such that $E_1E_2\cdots E_rA=\text{RREF(A)}$ and $F_1,...,F_s$ such that $F_1F_2\cdots F_sB=\text{RREF(B)}=\text{RREF(A)}$. Therefore $P=(F_1F_2\cdots F_s)^{-1}E_1E_2\cdots E_r$

Comment: @DavidP does same solution space necessarily imply same RREF?

Comment: More simply, say $B = PA$, equivalently $P^{-1}B = A$.  Then, if $Ax = 0$, then $PAx = P0 = 0$, so $Bx = 0$.  Conversely, if $Bx = 0$, then $P^{-1}Bx = P^{-1}0 = 0$, so $Ax = 0$.  So the solution spaces are the same.  No need to decompose into elementary matrices.

Comment: @user148177 How do you justify the existence of such an invertible $P$ in the first place?

Comment: Oh, right, that only gives one direction.  Yeah, for the other direction you need the above technique.

Comment: @Vim Yes. Two matrices are row-equivalent if and only if row operations transform one into the other (this is the definition). Row operations correspond to multiplications on the left by elementary matrices. This is usually proved in undergraduate linear textbooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field is irrelevant. Let $\{Bx_1,\ldots,Bx_k\}$ be a basis of the column spaces of $B$. Since $A, B$ have the same null space, every nontrivial linear combination of $\{Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_k\}$ must be a nonzero vector. In other words, $\{Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_k\}$ is a linearly independent set. Therefore there exists a bijective linear transformation $P$ (defined on $K^m$) that maps each $Ax_j$ to $Bx_j$. As $A$ and $B$ have identical null spaces, it follows that $PA=B$.

Comment: I understand why $P$ transforms each $Ax_j$ to $Bx_j$ bijectively, but how to show that $P$ is bijective on *the whole space*?

Comment: thank you sir. It's clear now.

Comment: @Vim Sorry, I've made some mistakes in my previous comments. What I really meant is this: let $\{Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_k,u_{k+1},\ldots,u_m\}$ and $\{Bx_1,\ldots,Bx_k,v_{k+1},\ldots,v_m\}$ be two bases of $K^m$; now define $P(Ax_j)=Bx_j$ and $Pu_j=v_j$.

Comment: That's alright ${}{}{}$